# Taking log transform for Z axis in sns.kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to take log transform on the z axis for the given plot so that i can see the data present in the graph where it is sparse. But i am not able to see how to do it.

```
sns.kdeplot( x , y , cmap='gist_gray_r', shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
```

Image from above command is attached below, (x, y are 2 lists of data).
Can anyone help with how to take the log transform (i.e) apply log to the z axis.

[image: Image for above command]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn's kdeplot won't be able to directly take a log into account. But you can manually call the [kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), calculate the value over a grid and take the log. And then manually create a contour plot.

However, if the x and y arrays aren't extremely large, the kde won't have much meaningful information in the sparse areas. Everything will be smoothed out.

Another idea is a `scatterplot`. Using a comma marker (`marker=','`) and removing the dot edges (`linewidth=0`) very small dots can be drawn. Depending on the number of dots, a smaller alpha can be used. A scatter plot has the benefit of showing the data as they really are, instead of an arbitrary approximation via a kde.

The code below creates an example of the 3 approaches. X and Y axes are shared to illustrate the much larger area occupied by the logscale levels.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

x = np.random.normal(np.tile([0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.06], 10000), 0.01)
y = np.random.normal(np.tile([-0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.9], 10000), 0.4)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(14, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

# create a regular kdeplot
sns.kdeplot(x, y, cmap='gist_gray_r', shade=True, shade_lowest=False, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('standard kdeplot')

# create a kdeplot with logscale levels
kde = gaussian_kde([x, y])
xmin, xmax = x.min() - 0.02, x.max() + 0.02
ymin, ymax = y.min() - 0.8, y.max() + 0.8
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 50), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 50))
z = kde([xs.ravel(), ys.ravel()]).reshape(xs.shape)
N = 10
levels = np.logspace(-6, np.log10(z.max()), N + 1)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno_r', N)
axes[1].contourf(xs, ys, z, levels=levels, colors=[cmap((i + 1) / N) for i in range(N)], alpha=0.5)
axes[1].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True) # 'sharey' removes the ticks, here they are added again
axes[1].set_title('kdeplot with logscale levels')

# draw a scatter plot
sns.scatterplot(x, y, color='r', marker=',', linewidth=0, s=1, alpha=0.2, ax=axes[2])
axes[2].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True)
axes[2].set_title('scatterplot')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Another idea is to combine a regular kdeplot with a scatterplot for the faraway points:

```py
ax = sns.kdeplot(x, y, cmap='gist_gray_r', shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
sns.scatterplot(x, y, color='grey', marker=',', linewidth=0, s=1, alpha=1, zorder=0, ax=ax)
```

[image: combined plot]

Comment: Oh nice johan combining is a nice idea. Thanks for it.

Comment: I just added the code to manually create logscale contours for the kde